# How to merge the segments in Lucene(Solr)

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a scenario that I need to merge the solr indexes online.
I have a primary solr index of 100 Gb and it is serving the end users and it can't go offline for a moment. Everyday new lucene indexes(2 GB) are generated separately.

I have tried [Merging Indexes: coreadmin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes)

Even I tried the IndexWriter API [AddIndexes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addIndexes(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory...). But no luck.

And it will create a new core or new folder. which means it will copy 100Gb every time to a new folder.

Is there a way I can do a segment level merging?

Comment: Instead of merging why don't you index the new data into primary index in the first place.

Comment: Primary index will serve the end users and 500k+ docs are getting added every day. I don't have a bandwidth to index directly to the primary because my end users are getting affected by this. That's the reason am generating lucene index from another machine and trying to merge with primary. Is there any work around for my scenario?

Comment: Possibly you cannot index the documents in the realtime as your users are getting affected. But you can collect this and then load it at once in the off hours (middle of night). Did you consider that.

Comment: But not as post request. Am trying to perform index merging without bringing the solr down. Is there a solution for this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I understand that you are merging the index, Please don't feel offended. I am saying You can index the daily collected data, in the primary as a daily indexing job. Also are you performing `optimize` command on the index with fixed number of segments?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about merging two cores.

I will answer for solr5.

You can [merge with the core api](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-MERGEINDEXES).
You can merge with lucene outsite from solr, [create a core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE) and then [switch with the old one](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-SWAP).

If you are using SolrCloud you can use a list of cores for your collection via [ALIAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api4) or `Migrate Documents` from new core to your central core.